# Cannot open database ASP.NET Core Database first

Tags: asp.net-core, ef-database-first, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I'm trying to set up a new project in ASP.Net Core using an existing database.

When I run the following console command, however, I get a login failed error.

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=TeamAllyLibrary;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

I get the following error each time.

```
Cannot open database "TeamAllyLibrary" requested by the login. The login failed.
```

Comment: You are using trusted connection and your account is not permitted to access the database or the server / database doesn't exist at all. Use the sa user.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. Using `Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb` was connecting to the wrong SQL server instance. (Not sure what instance it was using) So the database I was trying to connect to was not being found.